# Exporting ASPNETDB.MDF to an external database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, aspnetdb

ASP.Net 4.0/C#/MSSQL/Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Hey I am now at the stage where I want to move a project to a live server

Now I want to move the tables from the ASPNETDB file in the App_Data folder
to the server.

I have used the `Aspnet_regsql.exe` tool to successfully generate the following tables
on my shared hosted server

`dbo.aspnet_Applications`
`dbo.aspnet_Membership`
`dbo.aspnet_Paths`
`dbo.aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers`
`dbo.aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser`
`dbo.aspnet_Profile`
`dbo.aspnet_Roles`
`dbo.aspnet_SchemaVersions`
`dbo.aspnet_Users`
`dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles`
`dbo.aspnet_WebEvent_Events`

Now what is the next step to essentially copy the tables from ASPNETDB.MDF
to these tables on the server?

Many thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What version of SQL server have you got?**

If you can open the database locally in SQL Management Studio you can just use `Generate Scripts` that you can then simply open and run on your production server. It has the option to copy

- Data
- Schema
- Both

So you can start with an empty database on Production and copy both the data and schema at once with a single .sql file and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Cool, so right click on the database and go `Generate Scripts`.

Comment: I was unable to open ASPNETDB in mssql server management studio to generate the script file, although I found a way to generate the script in Visual Studio. Right click ASPNETDB.MDF (in server explorer) Click "publish to provider", follow the wizard through and save it to the desktop, then open it in mssql server management studio and hit Execute. It looks to have completed successfully.

Comment: @noscript great, hope you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the export data feature from the management studio to migrate the data from the msf file to the live dtabse.

Answer (score 0):

You are really better off putting all the membership etc. tables, views and stored procs into the main database for your production application. You can do this with the Database Publishing Wizard, which will create a script to recreate everything including all the data. No need to use two separate databases.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one can run this exe to copy empty tables from ASPNETDB.mdf to external SQL server.
drive:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\aspnet_regsql.exe